# How to redirect double URL to single URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Google Search Console is showing 404 Page Not Found error for

```
https://example.com/page/https://example.com/page/
```

and the link is coming from an external website.

I want to redirect with `.htaccess`:

```
https://example.com/page/https://example.com/page/
```

to

```
https://example.com/page/
```

Can anyone can help me in this regard?

Comment: You do _not_ want to do that. It is obvious that this external has an issue and creates invalid links. Now certainly you _could_ try to handle that symptom and forward requests (instead of curing the cause which _always_ is the better idea). But that has consequences: you will end up having those invalid links in the google index which makes your site look bad and get a reduction in ranking in the end...

Comment: @arkascha "you will end up having those invalid links in the google index which makes your site look bad and get a reduction in ranking in the end..." - that's nonsense, providing you 301 redirect the invalid inbound link. Google _might_ still report the source URL if you do a `site:` search, but it won't appear in normal Google searches and nor will it result in a reduction in ranking. (?)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following mod_rewrite directives at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*?)https?:/ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This just removes any trailing part on the URL-path that starts `http:/` (or `https:/`).

**UPDATE:** The `?` in the capturing subpattern `(.*?)` makes it non-greedy, so it only captures up to the first occurrence of `https:/` and discards the rest, rather than up to the *last occurrence* (greedy) and *looping* (redirect loop) until all occurrences of `https:/` were removed.

Additional notes:

- First test with 302 (temporary) redirect to make sure it works. Only change to 301 when confirmed, to avoid caching issues.
- The URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* has already had sequences of slashes reduced to single slashes, so you can't match `//` (double slash) here (but I don't think you need to).
- If there are query strings involved then you may need a slightly different approach and another directive, since the query string itself (as opposed to the URL-path) might contain the "repeated URL" that needs to be removed (we would need to see an example first). The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, not the query string.
- On Windows: If the (scheme and) colon (`:`) appears in the first path segment (ie. the malformed link is for the document root) then Apache will generate a 403 Forbidden *before* `.htaccess` is able to redirect. There is nothing you can do to avoid this since it is a limitation of the OS (colons are not allowed in filesystem paths - the 403 occurs when Apache tries to map the URL to a filesystem path). This does not happen on Linux. For example: `https://example.com/https://example.com/`.

---

**UPDATE:** If you are not seeing a redirect, just a 404 then you may need to enable *additional pathname information* (PATH_INFO) on your URLs. For example, at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
```

Comment: Thank You @MrWhite, but no luck. Showing 404 Not Found Error!

Comment: Does the redirect occur? If not then you may need to enable PATH_INFO. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The leading `.*` zero-or-more quantifier is IMHO very likely to mess things up and causes looping redirects, etc. This is why I added a slash in front of it in my answer.

Comment: @wp78de I'm not sure how `.*` would cause looping, unless there are multiple instances of `http:/` in the URL (there would be one redirect for each instance - which shouldn't be a problem) - but that wouldn't be solved by including a slash? However, I've changed this to non-greedy (`.*?`) so that it strips everything after the first occurrence - no looping redirects. If you include a slash then it won't match requests for the document root or URLs that don't end in a slash (although that may not be a problem for the OP).